# What is the use of $ in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone please tell me what is the use of $ in angularjs and what it stands for. What is the difference between $scope and scope.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same as the difference between `window` and `indow` - "$" is just like any other character in variable name

Comment: is nothing more than a variable prefix ... most likely used to denote a core angular service so it is easy to tell where it comes from

Comment: https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/scope-vs-scope

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/-w6FAkpDYzM

Answer (score 3):

In context, the $ is used as a *prefix* for identifiers of "intrinsic AngularJS use".

In particular it is used to denote AngularJS-common modules/objects/functions and the convention for $scope. From the [AngularJS style guide](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide):

> Do not use $ prefix for the names of variables, properties and methods. This prefix is reserved for AngularJS usage.

This same prefix approach has been used by other libraries/vendors.

Comment: It is pretty cool that you stick with the default name (user****) and have a high reputation. Thanks for the answer :)